# Cancellation of a given schedule by an airline

Tags: air-travel, airlines, cancellations

Is there a resource that provides information about an upcoming permanent cancellation of a given route or a particular scheduled slot on a route if there are multiple flights during the day?

If not how would one go about finding this information save waiting for an announcement by a news site?

Comment: If you would search for that particular flight on the airline's website (on that specific day) and it doesn't come back with the search wouldn't that confirm it's cancelled?

Comment: @DiscoFever That would only come up if you try to book the flight.  What if it's already been booked?

Comment: I would think you could do a new search similar to the one you did when you booked the flight.  (acting like you're going to book the same flight again)

Comment: @DiscoFever Doesn't that sound counterintuitive to do that first of all?  2nd That may not help since the fare that may be available for that flight due to its popularity may not show until page 2-3 of available tickets.

Comment: If you have already booked the flight, most airlines will tell you pretty quickly if they have cancelled it.

Comment: @DJClayworth They did.  But that's not the point.

Answer (score 4):

Airlines tend not to announce discontinuation of routes too far in advance, as it would effect sales of that route on dates prior to shut down.  As long as they have a plane flying a route, they want the seats as full as possible.

Plus there is the aspect that decisions to shutdown a route are not made far in advance, airlines start a route and they do their best to make if profitable. the decision to shut down the route comes only after the airline has exhausted options to improve bookings on that route.

In many cases the announcement of a route shutdown is not made public immediately. Often elite flyers effected by the route shutdown are the first to hear, followed by high producing travel agents, then eventually the general news outlets and public.